# Scala 3 type bound `<:<` trick for tuples

Tags: scala, types, scala-macros, scala-3

During online session Adam Warski showed a trick to prove that tuple has a certain structure:

The first implementation is

```scala
    def sequence[T <: Tuple](t: T): Option[InverseMap[T, Option]] =
        val unwrapped = t.productIterator.collect { case Some(v) => v}.toArray[Any]
        if unwrapped.length == t.productArity then Some(Tuple.fromArray(unwrapped).asInstanceOf[InverseMap[T, Option]])
        else None
```

which allows (but shouldn't)

```scala
sequence(("x", true)) // compiles
```

And implementation with a trick

```scala
def betterSequence[T <: Tuple](t: T)(using T <:< Map[InverseMap[T, Option], Option]): Option[InverseMap[T, Option]] =
    val unwrapped = t.productIterator.collect { case Some(v) => v}.toArray[Any]
    if unwrapped.length == t.productArity then Some(Tuple.fromArray(unwrapped).asInstanceOf[InverseMap[T, Option]])
    else None
```

```scala
betterSequence(("x", true)) // compile error
```

Could some explain how

```
(using T <:< Map[InverseMap[T, Option], Option])
```

works and why `T` is a subtype of `Map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InverseMap[T, Foo]` takes a tuple `T` that looks like `(Foo[t1], Foo[t2], ..., Foo[tn])` and turns it into a tuple `(t1, t2, ..., tn)`. If `T` does not have that structure, i.e. it's not a bunch of `Foo`s, it will not compile (with a somewhat cryptic error). This is the main thing that proves the tuple only has `Option`s in it.

The next question is how to insert this type into the `betterSequence` method. `Map[T, Foo]` turns a tuple `T` that looks like `(t1, t2, ..., tn)` into `(Foo[t1], Foo[t2], ..., Foo[tn])` (the inverse of `InverseMap`). Thus, `Map[InverseMap[T, Option], Option]` is just `T` (think of maths, where f(f^-1(x)) is again x. The bound `T <:< T` will always be true, but only if the `InverseMap` succeeds first.

Comment: True, didn't notice that we have the case of f(f^-1(x)). Thanks!